# Check if two ArrayList of points are symmetrics

Tags: android, math, arraylist, coordinates, points

I'm working on an Android app which lets a group of child to draw whatever they want in a specific area. I need to check if the lines and figure that they draw are symmetric. I save the points of each line they draw into an ArrayList, and all the lines are into another ArrayList. The problem is that since the app is designed to let them draw freehand, I don't know how to compare the lines by considering a certain flexibility. For example, I would consider symmetric these two figures in the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3cBx.jpg even if they have not the same inclination and the same length (so, in one of the arrayList there are less/more points). Do you have any suggestion? This is the code I use to store the points, so you can see the structure of the ArrayList:

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                points.add(new Pair<Float, Float>(touchX, touchY));
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                points.add(new Pair<Float, Float>(touchX, touchY));
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                points.add(new Pair<Float, Float>(touchX, touchY));
                drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                drawPath.reset();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
```